# MySql file per table idb file 65 rows 88GB in size?

Tags: database, magento1.9.3

I was hoping someone else may have come across this situation.

I have a table called **index_event** which is part of **Magento 1.9.3** and contains around **65 rows**.

Every so often the physical space taken up by the table bloats to around **88GB** but **no more than 10 rows are added to the table**.

Optimizing the table resolves the issue and takes it back down to around 2MB. I am completely stumped and am contemplating exporting the database, purging MySQL, re-installing and re-importing but thought I would see if anyone has come across anything like this before?

**Mysql version is 5.5**

Thanks in advance, Dave